# Very Slow Sequential Reads over NFS from an XFS disk in Amazon EC2

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, nfs, xfs

I am using tiobench to test performance of an NFS mounted volume, and notice that **Sequential Reads** are much slower than **Random Reads**. This isn't the behavior when I run the same test on the disk mounted locally.

Here is a little graph, with NFS in red and sequential reads on the left:

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

I am exporting the volume on the server like this

```
/export *.internal(no_subtree_check,rw,no_root_squash)
```

and mounting with this:

```
mount -o hard,intr,async,noatime,nodiratime,noacl $NFS_SERVER:/export /nfs
```

Additionally I am doing all this in amazon EC2, exporting an EBS volume with the XFS file system (redundant, I know).

I have tried using jumbo frames and various other mount options, but none seem to have much effect.

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 2):

How many times did you run each test?  IO throughput tends to be fairly random on EC2 due to over-sharing of resources.  Unless you ran each test at least 4 times, I don't know that your comparison results mean anything other than timing of shared loads.